# Accumulator of reduce function undefined if not returned. Why does it behave like this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeerror, reduce, higher-order-functions

Array to be reduced:

```
const users = [
    { firstname: "Sanket", lastname: "Shevkar", age: 22 },
    { firstname: "Aniket", lastname: "Bhalla", age: 45 },
    { firstname: "Tanvi", lastname: "Shinde", age: 21 },
    { firstname: "Saif", lastname: "Siddiqi", age: 67 },
  ];
const outout = users.reduce((acc, curr)=>{
                     if(curr.age<45){
                        acc.push(curr.firstname);
                     }
                }, [])
```

Throws TypeError:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

I have passed an empty array to initialize the `acc` (accumulator), but still it throws typeError. If I `return acc` at the end, it works perfectly.

```
const outout = users.reduce((acc, curr)=>{
                     if(curr.age<45){
                        acc.push(curr.firstname);
                     }
                     return acc;
                }, [])
```

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: _"Why does it behave like this?"_ - because that's how the specs say it should behave. https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-array.prototype.reduce (specifically step 9.c.ii)

Comment: Why would you use `reduce` to do the filtering, when you can just use `Array#filter` before `reduce`?

Comment: Because you need to return something on every iteration for it to be working fine. You can read more here https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/reduce-f47a7da511a9/

Answer (score 2):

Array.reduce must return accumulator on every loop

```js
const users = [
    { firstname: "Sanket", lastname: "Shevkar", age: 22 },
    { firstname: "Aniket", lastname: "Bhalla", age: 45 },
    { firstname: "Tanvi", lastname: "Shinde", age: 21 },
    { firstname: "Saif", lastname: "Siddiqi", age: 67 },
  ];
const outout = users.reduce((acc, curr)=>{
                     if(curr.age<45){
                        return acc.concat(curr.firstname);
                     }
                     return acc
                }, [])
                
                console.log(outout)
```

Comment: The asker already knows this. It's even in the question.